# Update table records with accumulated result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Lets say I have a table Tbl (Represents simple timelogs for work made on different customers)

Five columns
Id: int
TimeUse: float
IdCustomer: int
Created: DateTime
TimeCalc: float

I have a number of records in this table, (TimeCalc is initialized to value = 0)

What I want my SQL to do is:

when TimeUse for all foregoing records on a specific customer accumulates to a value < 10 then the value in TimeCalc should be 0

when TimeUse for all foregoing records on a specific customer accumulates to a value >= 10 then the value in TimeCalc should be = TimeUse for the record...

I have messed around with Case routines with subqueries, but can't get it working.

```
BEFORE
    Id        TimeUse       IdCustomer        Created        TimeCalc
    1         2             1                 14/09/09       0
    2         5             2                 14/09/10       0
    3         2             1                 14/09/11       0
    4         5             2                 14/09/12       0
    5         4             1                 14/09/13       0
    6         2             2                 14/09/14       0
    7         4             1                 14/09/15       0
    8         1             1                 14/09/16       0
    9         3             2                 14/09/17       0
    10        2             1                 14/09/18       0
    11        4             2                 14/09/19       0



AFTER
    Id        TimeUse       IdCustomer        Created        TimeCalc
    1         2             1                 14/09/09       0
    2         5             2                 14/09/10       0
    3         2             1                 14/09/11       0
    4         5             2                 14/09/12       0
    5         4             1                 14/09/13       0
    6         2             2                 14/09/14       2
    7         4             1                 14/09/15       0
    8         1             1                 14/09/16       1
    9         3             2                 14/09/17       3 
    10        2             1                 14/09/18       2
    11        4             2                 14/09/19       4
```

Can this be solved in an SQL update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do this with a cumulative sum:

```
select Id, TimeUse, IdCustomer, Created,
       (case when sum(timeuse) over (partition by idcustomer order by id) < 10 then 0
             else timeuse
        end) as timecalc
from table t;
```

You can do the same thing in earlier versions using `outer apply` or a subquery.

If you want an update, just use a CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when sum(timeuse) over (partition by idcustomer order by id) < 10 then 0
                   else timeuse
              end) as new_timecalc
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set timecalc = new_timecalc;
```

EDIT:

The following will work in any version of SQL Server:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when (select sum(t2.timeuse)
                         from table t2
                         where t2.idcustomer = t.idcustomer and
                               t2.id <= t.id
                        ) < 10 then 0
                   else timeuse
              end) as new_timecalc
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set timecalc = new_timecalc;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks.. Will any of these apply to SQL server 2012?

Comment: @Beaker . . . All of them.

Comment: Are you sure you are using SQL Server 2012 with the correct compatibility mode?

Comment: Since I do not know what you mean by Compatibility Mode I must say no :)

Comment: The latest Edit worked. Not sure why the others do not-

Comment: Sorry. Had made a mixup between our SQL servers. This one is actually a SQL Server 2008. Explains things. Thanks again